# Beginner: Trying to run an sum/average class getting an error

Tags: java, arrays, sum, average

When I run this class I am not getting a the sum/average.  I am getting an error listed below.  I am not sure why I am getting it. I am a student very new at this.

```
public class DebugEight2
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int[] someNums = {4,17,22,8,35};
    int tot;
    int x;
    int sum = 0;
    for(x = 0; x <= someNums.length; ++x)
      tot = someNums[x];
      sum = sum + someNums[x];
    System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
    System.out.println("Average is " + sum * 1.0 / someNums.length);
    }
}
```

### Error:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException: 4 at DebugEight1.main (DebugEight1.java:17)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Array index starts from `0` and goes till it's `length -1`  See that `<=` in your `for` loop. So this `for(x = 0; x <= someNums.length; ++x)` should be `for(x = 0; x < someNums.length; ++x)`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your loop condition, remove the equal sign like this

```
for(x = 0; x < someNums.length; ++x)
```

You should also wrapp the code which is supposed to be inside the loop into brackets (without them, only the next line after the for loop condition will be executed)

```
for(x = 0; x < someNums.length; ++x) {
  tot = someNums[x];
  sum = sum + someNums[x];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are zero based and their indices go from `0` to `someNums.length -1`

You not only exceeding the bounds of the array but the variable `sum` is being assigned outside of scope of the loop. Adjust the upper bounds of the array and add braces:

```
for (x = 0; x < someNums.length; x++) {
    tot = someNums[x];
    sum = sum + someNums[x];
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

1. You want to iterate while `x` is lesser than `someNums.length;` since max index in array is `arraysLength - 1`, so change `x <= someNums.length;` to `x < someNums.length;` in `for` loop
2. There is no need for `tot` (I assume it should store total numbers) variable because you already have `someNums.length` which represents how many numbers you summed. BTW you already are calculating `avg` using `sum` and `someNums.length`. So you can safely remove

   ```
   tot = someNums[x];
   ```

   from your code.

Answer (score 0):

first you should remove `=` from `<= someNums.length;` i will look like this `< someNums.length;`  and then change `++x` to `x++` if you put `++x` when loop starts it will check condition `< someNums.length;` and then pluse one **+1** to **x** and so on, currently your array length is **5** when loop goes on last increment its size is 6 and there is no item on **6** location thats why it is throwing exception so you have you change it `++x` to `x++`

```
public class DebugEight2
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int[] someNums = {4,17,22,8,35};
    int tot;
    int x;
    int sum = 0;
    for(x = 0; x <someNums.length; x++) /// just change here
      tot = someNums[x];
      sum = sum + someNums[x];
    System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
    System.out.println("Average is " + sum * 1.0 / someNums.length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did is you looped beyond the scope of the array. Try doing someNums.length, you will get the number 5.

Going to your for loop we now know that it starts at 0 and increments until it gets to 5. And the for loop is traversing over the array and is pointing at the positions in your array.

So let's traverse through your loop.

At x = 0, someNums[x] = 4.

At x = 1, someNums[x] = 17,

At x = 2, someNums[x] = 22,

At x = 3, someNums[x] = 8,

At x = 4, someNums[x] = 35,

As you can see, your array has now ended, you no longer have any more elements to traverse over. But we have previously stated that your for loop increments until it gets to 5.

So at x = 5, someNums[x] will have to give you an error since you are pointing at a position and trying to retrieve information from that position that essentially does not exist.

There are two ways to solve your problem:

1. You change the loop to `for(int x = 0; x < someNums.length; x++)`
2. You change the loop to `for(int x = 0; x <= someNums.length - 1; x++)`

These will solve your problem because they will stop your loop at 4 and not at 5, therefore you will no longer receive an error.